# Using bootstrap inside Svelte Custom Element

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'd like to use bootstrap inside a svelte component, so i can use a popover Menu. The problem is that the css works well but the js isn't loading correctly, so when I compile the component the popover doesn't work. Is there a way to make it work? I can't find a lot of resource, also using Popover.js would be useful but I can't get it to work in a compiled custom element.

I tried adding the cdn inside the entry page (index.js) , I can see the script inside developer tools , but no JS.
Also having the js in local and importing it doesn't work, any idea on how to fix this?
Also other frameworks that would be easier for this. ( I tried Lit Elements, but the community doesn't seem that active)

Answer (score 1):

I have gone into a similar issue recently, and here's how I solved it:

Objective: I am trying to build a custom web component that can be used on any framework like React, Vue, Angular js 1.8, or just vanilla JS and basic HTML and CSS. I want to use Bootstrap as the UI of my web component.

Goal: Build a custom web component with Bootstrap and Svelte and bundle it such that the user only needs a bundle.css and bundle.js to use this component properly

Procedure:

Component.svelte:

```
<svelte:options tag="my-component" />

<script>
    import '../scss/styles.scss';

/**
 * @type {string}
 */
export let name;

</script>

<h1>Hi! {name}, Been Ngai Bang?</h1>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Click me</button>

<style>
/** only uncomment it before npm run build **/
/** @import 'path/to/style.css'; **/
</style>
```

styles.scss:

```
// 1. Include functions first (so you can manipulate colors, SVGs, calc, 
etc)
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";

// // 2. Include any default variable overrides here

// // 3. Include remainder of required Bootstrap stylesheets
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";


// // 4. Include any default map overrides here

// // 5. Include remainder of required parts
@import "~bootstrap/scss/maps";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/root";

// // 6. Include any needed components here
@import "~bootstrap/scss/_buttons";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/_forms";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/_list-group";
```

main.js:

```
import MyComponent from './lib/MyComponent.svelte';
```

vite.config.js:

```
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import autoPreprocess from 'svelte-preprocess'
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer';
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '~bootstrap': path.resolve(__dirname, 
'node_modules/bootstrap'),
            '~bootstrap-icons': path.resolve(__dirname, 
'node_modules/bootstrap-icons'),
        },
    browser: true, // Resolve packages in browser
    dedupe: ['svelte'], // Deduplicate Svelte
},
plugins: [
    // Only enable sveltekit() in development mode
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' && sveltekit(),
],
build: {
    emptyOutDir: true,
    outDir: 'path/to/output/dir',
    lib: {
        // Could also be a dictionary or array of multiple entry points
        entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/main.js'),
        name: 'SvelteBundle',
        // the proper extensions will be added
        fileName: 'bundle',
    },
    rollupOptions: {
        plugins: [
            svelte({
                preprocess: autoPreprocess({
                    postcss: {
                        plugins: [autoprefixer()]
                    }
                }),
                compilerOptions: {
                    customElement: true,
                },
            }),
            resolve(),
        ],
    }
}
});
```

Justification:
The above snippets meets the goal by compiling all the needed css(including the needed bootstraps) into `style.css` and all the component code into `bundle.js`. During usage, the user only needs to import `bundle.js`, and the component itself will handle the ui import with the `@import /path/to/style.css`. The reason we import it inside the component is because svelte custom web component is [isolated](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-custom-element-api) and does not get any css from the outside scopes. So, we have to import it directly inside the component. But since the css that we are importing is actually the generated style.css, we don't have to worry about a big-size bootstrap.css and this file will only be imported once even if you have multiple components using style.css.

Comment: How can I add a component that need Bootstrap's JS? Like a popover element or maybe a modal

Comment: You may simply import them and initialize them in `onMount`. [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/tooltips/) might be a good example.

However, now looking back to this question, I would suggest you to give up svelte's custom element if you want to use the component in more advanced matter in addition to just displaying data. I would suggest using [client side component api](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-client-side-component-api) to do it.

Comment: i can't initialize them because i can't get the elements by query selector

Answer (score -1):

Configuring bootstrap for use in Svelte is pretty tricky. You could use [Sveltestrap](https://sveltestrap.js.org/?path=/story/components--get-started), a UI library to achieve this with ease...